Shift a box to another line
I have a question. I'm creating a TOC from scratch. Some lines are too long, and to solve this, I came up with something like this (obviously, this is much more simplified than the actual code). The \fbox are just to make it easier to see.
\usepackage[left=6cm, right=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
        \fboxsep0pt
        \parindent0pt
        \box_new:N\l_number_box
        \box_new:N\l_page_box
        \box_new:N\l_entry_box
        \tl_new:N\l_entry_tl
        \dim_new:N\l_yshift_page_dim
        \dim_new:N\l_entry_wd_dim
        
        \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnn\l_number_box{1.5em}{{\bfseries 2}}
        \hbox_set:Nn\l_page_box{\fbox{123}}
        \tl_set:Nn\l_entry_tl{\lipsum[1][1-2]\dotfill}
        %width of entry--
        \dim_set:Nn\l_entry_wd_dim{\linewidth - \box_wd:N\l_number_box - \box_wd:N\l_page_box}
        \hsize\l_entry_wd_dim
        
        %Calculate shift dim. (set vbox twice).
        \vbox_set:Nn\l_entry_box{\l_entry_tl}
        \dim_set:Nn\l_yshift_page_dim{-\box_dp:N\l_entry_box}
        \vbox_set_top:Nn\l_entry_box{\l_entry_tl}
        \dim_add:Nn\l_yshift_page_dim{\box_dp:N\l_entry_box}
        %--------------------------------------------------
        
        \fbox{\box_use:N\l_number_box}
        \fbox{\box_use:N\l_entry_box}
        \lower\l_yshift_page_dim
        \box_use:N\l_page_box
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

Obteniendo como resultado

or, without fbox

To ensure that the page box is aligned with the last line, what I do is move it a number of times equal to the difference between the dp of the vbox and the vtop.
My question is, is there any way to make this easier? I don't use baselineskip because I don't know how to control if a paragraph is breaking and into how many lines. Is there a way to find that out?




What are you trying to accomplish by creating a TOC from scratch that you can't achieve using a regular TOC and using something like the tocloft package?

you can just put the page number in the paragraph (with \dotfill\rlap{123} so it naturally aligns and appears in the margin

@KennethOdle For two reasons. I learn more about how things work, and I have complete control over what I want to do. I've attached an image to the post so you can see.

Hi, @DavidCarlisle. I thought about it, but for some reason, it seems like an inelegant solution to me haha. Thanks for your answer.

no, it is the standard solution for such things. Or if you wanted to look more expl3 and you have the section number aligned at the top and the page at the bottom you could use two poles of an L3 coffin, but that mechanism isn't really needed here, just a simple tex paragraph is all you need. You don't need any measuring or adjustments.

@DavidCarlisle Thanks!

From the entry for subsection 1.2.2 in the next-to-last example shown, the default for auto-generated TOCs is ragged right.  I think this 3-line entry should also be ragged right.

@barbarabeeton Hi, Barbara! Yes, indeed, those last two photos are mine (so, that TOC was generated by me, haha.), from the book we're putting together for a course at the Faculty of Economic Sciences at UNL (Argentina), for which I'm currently working on the index. Besides the left alignment, the lines don’t break, the dotted lines have to have a minimum length, etc. I have implemented all of that. The last photo is the implementation of a mini-index for the first page of a chapter. It only shows sections.

@gxono -- The comments by David C really do give the recommended approach.  I'd use a minipage (have to figure the proper width) with option [t] to align it with the number on the first line, and using \rlap to push the page number out of the minipage.  But I assume that, since you're doing this by hand, you know the widths of the areas on the left and the right, so may as well calculate the width of the area for the title up front.

How are you handling hyperref, are you going to insert the anchors manually?

Hi, @yannisl! Chapters, sections and subsections are redefined from scratch. In \section for example
there is \label{toc-sec:\int_use:N\l_chapter_int.\int_use:N\l_section_int}. All entries are saved in an external file and when I call it to make the index I use \pageref ;)
